# Add CMake project as subproject in CMake project in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I have a directory layout like the following

```
projectA/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- src/
    |-- main.cpp
projectB/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- src/
    |-- file1.cpp
    |-- file1.hpp
    |-- file2.hpp
    |-- main.cpp
|-- third_party/
    |-- include
        |-- lib1
```

I opened both project successfully in Qt Creator (using Ctrl+O and open the `CMakeLists.txt` file) and they're are able to build and run independently.

I need to gain access to `file1.Xpp` and `file2.hpp` from `projectA`. Is there a way in Qt Creator to add `projectB` as a subproject in `projectA`? And One might keep in mind that `file1.Xpp` and `file2.hpp` might depend on the third party library.

Using `Ctrl+N` -> `Other Project` -> `Subdirs Project` I can add a subproject, but only an empty one, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Do you compile projectA with a dependency+include of projectB ? I believe this is more on the CMake level than in the Qt Creator configuration.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add a CMake subject as a sub project.

Sub project is based of **qmake**.